# (Javascript) Definitely can't return an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, return, undefined

I've been watching for a while the questions here in Stack Overflow about returning arrays on JavaScript, but not a single answer works in my code. It always returns 'undefined'.

This is the important part of the code:

```
function VisualizadorIzquierdo () {
    // some stuff here
    this.dibujar = function () {
        var datos = obtenerDatos(0);
        alert(datos);                         //<--- This always returns 'undefined'
        // other stuff here
    }
    // more stuff here
}

function obtenerDatos(id) {                                                                             
    var xmlhttp = ConstructorXMLHttpRequest();
    if(!xmlhttp) alert('Error: No se pudo crear el objeto XMLHttpRequest');
    else {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText); //<--- This returns '[1,2,3,4]'    
                return xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', rutaLector + '?archivo=' + archivos[id], false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);     
    }
}
```

I'v tried defining the variable *datos* as a *new Array()* and *new Object()*. Also I'm trying returning an Object (like *{"arreglo" : [1,2,3,4]}*), defining a *new Array()* and *new Object()* within *obtenerDatos(id)* function, changing between syncronic and asyncronic, etc ...

But every time it returns 'undefined' :c

So, How can I definitely return an Array from a function?

Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: Assuming that the data returned from your _asynchronous_ call is valid, your alert will be executed prior to the code being returned, hence the undefined.

Comment: @j08691 if I delete the alerts, it also doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

`obtenerDatos()` don't have a `return`. The only 'return' in its context is inside another function that is being dynamically declared to the `onreadystatechange`, but that one doesn't count. Its a delayed event, that will be ran at some other time when the AJAX request is concluded. `obtenerDatos()` itself isn't returning anything.

What you have to do is set up a callback function that will be called with the AJAX response to process it once the AJAX is done fetching the data.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) might explain it better.

Comment: But if I set the *asyncronic* param to *false*, the declaration *var datos = obtenerDatos(0);* does move forward?

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that `obtenerDatos()` is not returning anything. `onreadystatechange` is, but its going nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are getting undefined is because you are calling `obtenerDatos()` which then calls

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

`xmlhttp.send(null);` <-- is an asynchronous call. so you `obtenerDatos()` function immediately returns after that. and since you don't have a return statement returning anything for obtenerDatos then the variable `datos` will get nothing or undefined as it is doing right now.

Comment: How can I make it to wait until the asynchronous call ends before returning *nothing*? (is that even possible?)

Comment: straight from the docs. the open function accepts these parameters

void open(DOMString method, DOMString url, optional boolean async, optional DOMString? user, optional DOMString? password);
the the one that says async? thats where.
here is a link to the docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Try in jQuery.

```
function VisualizadorIzquierdo () {
    // some stuff here
    obtenerDatos(0).done(function (result) {
        //var datos = obtenerDatos(0);
        alert(result);                        
        // other stuff here
    });
    // more stuff here
}


function obtenerDatos(id) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: rutaLector + '?archivo=' + archivos[id],
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) { },
        error: function () { },
        traditional: true
    });
}
```